# One to many relationship view data in a single row SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, inner-join

Here are three tables:

Table1: MedicineForPrescription

| Id | MedicineID | prescriptionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 14 | 14481 |
| 13 | 15 | 14481 |
| 14 | 16 | 14481 |

Table2: Prescription

| Id | PatientId |
| --- | --- |
| 14481 | 1 |

Table3: Patient

| Id | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | Suan |

I want to show Like

| FirstName | LastName | PrescriptionId | Medicine1 | Medicine2 | Medicine3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sam | suan | 14481 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

Can anyone please provide me the sql server query?

Comment: Can you give the query that you have tried so far? This is a simple case of joining three tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed maximum number of medecines per patient prescription, you can join the tables, then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select pa.firstName, pa.lastName, me.prescriptionId,
    max(case when me.rn = 1 then medecineId end) as medecine1,
    max(case when me.rn = 2 then medecineId end) as medecine2,
    max(case when me.rn = 3 then medecineId end) as medecine3
from patient pa
inner join prescription pr on pr.patientId = pa.id
inner join (
    select me.*, row_number() over(partition by prescriptionId order by id) rn
    from medecineForPrescription me
) me on me.prescriptionId = pr.id
group by pa.id, pa.firstName, pa.lastName, me.prescriptionId
```